# Mongodb merge update nested fields in a subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am searching if it exists, in mongodb or its nodejs driver, any method to merge/update a subdocument like this:

- The sample document, for example in collection `C`:

```
{
    subdocument: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }
}
```

- The update query that I do NOT want to use:

```
db.C.updateOne(
    {},
    {
        $set: {
            "subdocument.b": 3
        }
    }
}
```

- The update query that I want to use:

```
db.C.updateOne(
    {},
    {
        $set: {
            subdocument: {
                b: 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- The resulting document I get when running such a query:

```
{
    subdocument: {
        b: 3
    }
}
```

- The resulting merged document I would like to get instead:

```
{
    subdocument: {
        a: 1,
        b: 3
    }
}
```

For the record, the reason I want this is because I'm trying to use interfaces to avoid as much as possible writing schema keywords inside strings, so I can have as many of them checked by the typescript compiler as possible. So i know the way to do this is to update "subdocument.b", but I am exactly trying to not do this, to avoid using a string.

Obviously, the subdocument is not merged but fully replaced using the standard update witout options. I would like to know if there is a way to do this natively using mongodb query language, aggregation framework, mongodb nodejs driver, or maybe something else? From what i could learn by myself, it seems unsupported, but maybe it is and someone can tell me how?

Thanks

Comment: just thinking cant you maybe first find the document, if found based on the object being passed, take the result replace the result object(subdocument) value `b`, and set/update passing that new object to do the update. You can even check if its exist in the object if not just add, or update. In this way the object keeps his current values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy to do that if you use pipeline updates MongoDB >= 4.2
With pipeline updates all aggregate operators can be used, but only limited stages [see the database command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/) , drivers use that internally.

If you use pipeline updates you can use only aggregation operators, or query operators for the `$match`, only if you use `$expr`.The old update operators doesn't work inside a pipeline.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u7CQiB56icb)

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "subdocument": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$subdocument",
          {
            "b": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```